# Twig: negate containment operator IN

Tags: templates, twig, operators, symfony

I'm trying to negate [IN](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html#containment-operator).

Basically, I want to output *true*, when `keyword1` is in `keywords`, but `keyword11` isn't.

**Please note**: `keyword11` *("my_keyword_11")* starts with `keyword1` *("my_keyword_1")*. `keywords` has to stay a string, can't split/explode by the comma.

```
{% set keywords  = 'my_keyword_1, my_keyword_2' %}
{% set keyword1  = 'my_keyword_1' %}
{% set keyword11 = 'my_keyword_11' %}

{% if ((keyword1 in keywords) and (keyword11 not in keywords)) %}
    true 
{% endif %}
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: i'm a little bit confused. [Your code on twigfiddle seems works as expected](http://twigfiddle.com/4r26t2)?

Comment: @Matteo Thanks, you're right. I found a typo within the `keywords`, which is actually a bit more complex, than in my example. Post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is ok as you can view in this [twigfiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/4r26t2)